# Unable to load a saved gensim model, cannot reshape array of size 974897576 into shape (6828798,300)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to load a saved word2vec model. The file on loading throws error: cannot reshape array of size 974897576 into shape (6828798,300)

I've created a word2vec model by initialising 6828798 words to random vectors, by feeding a list of list of my vocabulary words `[['a', 'b', 'c']]` to gensim and running the model.

new_titles_grp is a pandas df, with synon_title (str) and averages (np.array.shape=(300,)) columns

```
sentences = [new_titles_grp['synon_title'].tolist()]
model_gensim = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, size=300)
```

Then, i'm replacing all the vectors with my pre-computed vector values, (all are (300,) dimensions) with

```
for ind, row in new_titles_grp.iterrows():
    model_gensim.wv.syn0[model_gensim.wv.vocab[row['synon_title']].index] = row['averages']

model_gensim.init_sims(replace=True) #doing this to normalize the values
```

The model works well when called in the same notebook

```
model_gensim.most_similar(get_job_title('Data Science'), topn=20)
Out[26]: 
[('Senior Data Scientist', 0.9982969760894775),
 ('DATA SCIENTIST', 0.9951386451721191),
 ('Data Scientist Analyst', 0.9940630197525024),
 ('Associate Data Scientist', 0.9907373189926147),
 ('Lead Data Scientist', 0.9906764030456543),
 ('Data Scientist Machine Learning Engineer', 0.9891946315765381),
 ('Data Scientist Specialist', 0.9885110855102539),
 ('Data Analyst Scientist', 0.988399863243103),
 ('Data Scientist III', 0.9873133301734924),
 ('Senior Data Scientist Machine Learning', 0.9868470430374146),
 ('Research Data Scientist', 0.98624187707901),
 ('Data Scientist Engineer', 0.9855831861495972),
 ('Data Scientist Intern', 0.9855802059173584),
 ('Machine Learning Specialist', 0.9842516779899597),
 ('Principal Data Scientist', 0.9835132360458374),
 ('Senior Manager Data Scientist', 0.9829919338226318),
 ('Machine Learning Engineer', 0.9829450249671936),
 ('Data Scientist IV', 0.9827083349227905),
 ('Data Analytics Engineer', 0.9825129508972168),
 ('Senior Data Scientist Consultant', 0.9823513031005859)]
```

On loading it in different notebook is throwing this error, I thought the numpy array dimensions are not same, which is not the case, all are 300 (0-Dimension) vectors. Please help!!

EDIT:
I'm saving it using `model_gensim.save(SAVE_PATH+'/jd_w2v.bin')`

Also, using

`model_gensim.wv.save_word2vec_format('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/talent_lemma_collection/w2v_models_v_1/jd_w2v.bin', binary=True)`

I'm able to save them (apparently)

Loading it using

```
model_titles = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load(jd_titles_path)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 974897576 into shape (6828798,300)
```

and

```
model_titles = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(datapath(jd_titles_path), binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

Comment: Show your code for saving and loading the model, and the full error message/stack you're seeing.